# Access modal instance html either through jquery or AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

There is an element in the popup with class `<a class="btn pull-right"> Create<a>` for which i want to access the element either throigh jquery or angularjs.The following code results in undefined.why? The modal popup has an id `mymodal`

```
$scope.func1 = function (issuekey) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: /someapi,
                controller: 'editctrl',
                windowClass: '',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
};

applicationControllers.controller('editctrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$http', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http) {

console.log($(".btn.pull-right").html());  //undefined
console.log($("#mymodal").html());  //undefined           

};
```

Comment: Got a typo please remove extra `'` in controller declaration

Comment: @Rajeev, why do you need to access the element? It's likely there's another, more angular-ish solution for your problem.